# Can anyone explain why magento is doing this on reviews?

Tags: php, magento, templates, review

I have no idea why, but if you view this page:

http://www.awesomegti.com/review/product/list/id/50592/#customer-reviews

I feel like the page is trying to utilise either an old template, or multiple templates which is causing the design to get messed up. If you click 'Back to product' the correct template loads fine.

Can anyone guide me to the right place to check this configuration?

Comment: Well those can have 2 different templates because its an entirely different moudle... also keep in mind the class on the `body` tag will not be the same because of this... so if you are using the body class to target css thats probably why.

Answer (score 0):

The link you have shared utilizes **review modules list action**, while when we click on "Back to Main Product Info" link, it takes us to **catalog module >> product controller >> view action**

Both are managed by different layout xml file so both have different layout.

You can do either of two strategies:

1. Make layout of product review page identical by doing some css work
2. Call review form and reviews list on product view page under product reviews tab (which is not working correctly right now)